# Write a program that asks a user to enters pairs of numbers until they enter "quit". add the numbers using a function

Tags: javascript, for-loop, while-loop

"Write a program that asks a user to enters pairs of numbers until they enter "quit". As each pair of numbers is entered and validated, add the numbers using a function. The function will have two parameters for the pair of numbers and will return the sum. After the user enters "quit", output all the pairs of numbers and their sums."

This is my function below

```
function evaluatingUserInput() {
    
    // Variable declaration.
    var numberOne;
    var numberTwo;
    var total = 0;
    
    // While user input is not the string "quit" prompt the user again.
    while(numberOne != "quit"){

        numberOne = prompt("Please enter a number or quit to stop.");
        numberTwo = prompt("please enter a second number or quit to stop.");

        numberOne = Number(numberOne);
        numberTwo = Number(numberTwo);
        total = numberOne + numberTwo;
            
        document.write(numberOne + " + ");
        document.write(numberTwo + " = ");
        document.write(total);
        document.write("<br />");
    }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

I'm not too sure what you are trying to achieve, but I'll try to do my best to help you. I don't want to give you any false information.

First, instead of using `while()`, I would use `setInterval()`.

```
setInterval(function(){ 
 if (numberOne != "quit") {
  //the code you had inside while()
 }
}, 1);
```

Also, `document.write` will overwrite everything that you have on the document. So instead of doing that I would use this:

```
var number = document.createElement("P")
number.innerHTML = numberOne + " + " + numberTwo + " = " + total;
document.body.appendChild(number)
```

Comment: `setInterval()` is absolutely NO replacement for `while()`, not in the way you describe, and not in any other way.

Comment: So the goal of the function is to keep prompting the user for two numbers until they enter the string "quit". It wants you to take the first input, add it to the second input and output the answer. Repeating this until the user enters the string quit. the document.write exists inside of the funcion which prints to an html document.

Comment: @PeterB I would use it as a scheduled loop. That's how I would do it, I don't know why you have a problem with that. If you are trying to do it in a different way then there's no problem with that. but I have used `setInterval()` as a loop and it worked for me, for each milliseconds.

Comment: The meaning of the two is totally different. `setInterval(fn, t)` in practice means: run `fn` as soon as the system is idle and also at least `t` milliseconds have passed since the last invocation. Compare that to `while(condition) { ... }` which means: run the body statement as long as the `condition` equals true, and repeat this again as soon as the body ends. It's just *not at all the same*. The effect may seem similar because javascript is single threaded, but the **functionality behind both is totally different, and both serve totally different purposes**.

Comment: @PeterB I once tried to use `while()` one time. For some reason it didn't work. But what I was trying to achieve worked with `setInterval()`, so based on what I have done, `setInterval()` sometimes can, I didn't say always. So based on what I was trying to do that time, it worked. I can still use conditions with `if()` with `setInterval()`.